# How to insert value from parent table into child table on insertion into child table

Tags: mysql, delimiter

I want to insert a value in child table which is generated in parent table on new insertion.

Assume,

```
create table head (
head_id int primary key auto_increment,
table_type varchar(60) );

create table table1 (
t1_id int primary key,
name varchar(60) ,
foreign key (t1_id) references head(head_id)
);

create table table2 (
t2_id int primary key,
name varchar(60) ,
foreign key (t2_id) references head(head_id)
);
```

Creates 3 tables head and table1, table2.

I want whenever i insert values in table1 or table2,

```
insert into table1 (name) values('Hi');
```

the head and table1 insert these values,

```
select * from head;
id      table_type
.
.
5       table1

select * from table1;

t1_id      name
.
.
5          hi
```

note that head table is auto increasing the id. which is inserted into child table table1.
How to do that i tried following trigger but its not working.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    TRIGGER `t1` BEFORE INSERT
    ON `table1`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        insert into head (table_type) values ('table1');
        insert into table1 (t1_id,name) values (NEW.head(id),NEW.table1(name));
    END

$$
```

Any help would be appreciated.